# Syntax error when running Python script from AppleScript

Tags: python-3.x, macos, applescript

I am new to AppleScript: I just created an AppleScript to execute my python code but I am getting "syntaxerror: Invalid syntax" when I execute the AppleScript. My python script works if i execute it directly from Terminal. What I'm I missing? Here are the first few lines of my code - the error is triggered by the 2nd line of the code:

```
ipaddr = '192.168.2.254'
stream = os.popen(f'ping -c 4 {ipaddr}')
output = stream.read()

if '0 received' in output:
    print('Tunnel is down. Likely due to a network issue. Please contact Admin')
```

Comment: Can you share the full error?

Comment: Quick guess though - you have multiple python versions installed, and when you try to run it from AppleScript it executes it a process where an older python version that does support f-strings is present in the $PATH

Comment: tell current application
 do shell script "python $HOME/Desktop/Tunnel.to.SF/Rosie.py -d"
  --> error "  File \"/Users/jd/Desktop/Tunnel.to.SF/Rosie.py\", line 19
    stream = os.popen(f'ping -c 4 {ipaddr}')
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax" number 1

Comment: @Mureinik the system defaults to Python3 - but yeah I haven't removed python2. My scripts execute with Python3 by default

Answer (score 0):

I changed the keystroke of AppleScript from:

```
keystroke "/usr/local/bin/python ...."

keystroke "/usr/local/bin/python3 ..."
```